# PowerShell ComboBox echoes populated list

Tags: powershell, combobox

When my ComboBox gets populated, as in the following code:

```
    ForEach ($Item in $ComboBoxArray) 
{
    $ComboBox.Items.Add($Item)
}
```

It echos all the populated items on the console. Would anyone suggest how to mute showing of this list!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it by redirecting the output or cast the result to void. Example:

```
$ComboBox.Items.Add($Item) | Out-Null
```

Or

```
[void]$ComboBox.Items.Add($Item)
```

Comment: You might want to accept both this and the answer C.B. gave you in the other questions if they are correct. That's what we do here to confirm and show appreciation. ; )